# Automapper Serialize/Deserialize source string to list using resolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I am trying to map source string to `List<T>` for member but the value of the mapped member list property is always null.

Here is my code.

```
//Source model
public class Claims
{  
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string ClaimType {get; set; } 
    public string ClaimValue { get; set; } // produce json string [{"Action":"read","Status":"active"}]
}

// Dest model
public class ClaimsDto
{  
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ClaimType { get; set; } 
   public List<ResourceActions> ClaimValues { get; set; }
}


public class ResourceActions
{
  public string Action { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
}



CreateMap<ResourceActions, ResourceActions>();

CreateMap<Claims, ClaimsDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.ClaimValues,
 opt => opt.MapFrom( src=> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResourceActions>>(src.ClaimValue))) 
.ReverseMap();
```

Also tried with resolver like this.

```
 .ForMember(dto => dto.ClaimValues, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver,string>(src=>src.ClaimValue ))
```

The resolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<Claims, ClaimsDto, string, List<ResourceActions>>
{
    public List<ResourceActions> Resolve(Claims source, ClaimsDto destination, string sourceMember, List<ResourceActions> destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResourceActions>>(sourceMember);
        return context.Mapper.Map<List<ResourceActions>>(data); // not working
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResourceActions>>(sourceMember); // not working
    }
}
```

And the controller

```
var mapped = _mapper.Map<List<ClaimsDto>>(source); // success without exception but the list property is null.
```

Other properties are mapped except this `string` to `List<T>` property.

Comment: Please provide also your json

Comment: What is the value of `source`? I've tried out your code and it works for me.

Comment: **@rigoryants-artem** This source json needs to be map `[{"Action":"create","Status":"active"},{"Action":"read","Status":"active"},{"Action":"update","Status":"active"},{"Action":"delete","Status":"active"}]` to this destination property `public List<ResourceActions> ClaimValues { get; set; }`

Comment: **@Patko** can you create a repo to GitHub that how you did? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/patkec/AutoMapperSample

Comment: @Patko Did you succeed to map the json string to `List<T>`? Did you commented this line ?https://github.com/patkec/AutoMapperSample/blob/master/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs#L27

Comment: This is your comment :) I just c/p your code and adapted it so that it runs in a console. But yes, after the call to `Map` list is correctly populated.

Answer (score 2):

I think this profile should solve the issue:

```
public class MyMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MyMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Claims, ClaimsDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.ClaimValues, cfg => cfg.MapFrom((claim, _) =>
               JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IReadOnlyCollection<ResourceActions>>(claim.ClaimValue)));
    }
}
```

Here is [an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXCXxR):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyMapperProfile>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var someClaims = new List<Claims>
{
    new Claims { Id = 5, ClaimType = "Foo", ClaimValue = @"[{""Action"":""read"",""Status"":""active""}]" },
    new Claims { Id = 7, ClaimType = "Bar", ClaimValue = @"[{""Action"":""create"",""Status"":""disabled""}]" },
};

var result = mapper.Map<List<ClaimsDto>>(someClaims);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item));
}
```